# considerably improve and update or considerably improving and updatating

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm trying to write a motivation letter and I'm having doubts when writing a couple of sentences using ing termination or not.

1. To  enroll in this course will allow me to pursue my career goal of considerably improve and update my skills (vs considerably improving and updating my skills)
2. I worked remotely as a free-lancer for a company which challenged me to transmit data through ultrasound in air (vs challenged me to transmitting data through ultrasound in air )

More interested than in knowing which option is correct, I'm interested in understanding why. Just for the record I'm a Spanish speaking native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first sentence, the **-ing** suffix will produce a *gerund* that you want to use as a noun. Your "career goal" is **improving** and **updating** your skills.

You can also use the infinitive in a similar way, where your "career goal is **to improve**" your skills.

In either case, "goal of considerably improve" does not make grammatical sense.

For the second, your current choice is correct. Your alternative again does not make grammatical sense.

As a side note, the start of your first sentence might flow better if you change it to:

> Enrolling in this course will...

Its current form is technically correct, but you wouldn't normally start a sentence like that.

Comment: So could I say "pursue my career goal of considerably improving my skills and also pursue my career goal to considerably improve my skills (the goal would be itself improving)?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, but the first option sounds better. As an aside, you might want to remove "considerably" from your sentence; it makes it sound as if you are severely lacking in skills.